# Sum of values related to specific name in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am workng on a excel spreadsheet which will store specific timing data from a db report. The data will contain Name and value. 
In a separate table I have to show the distinct names and sum of all related numeric values. I am pretty sure that I have to use some kind of VLOOKUP. This is the simple table that is showing what I have to do:
[image]

Comment: Use SUMIF. Put this in R3 and drag down: `=SUMIF($F$2:$F$19,$Q3,$L$2:$L$19)`

Comment: Or you could just use a Pivot Table

Comment: Yes, as Ron said, a pivot table would be the proper solution here.